# after linux and nginx update php not working

Tags: linux, nginx

I was working nginx 1.19 version. And installed PHP5-FPM on my linux server. My nginx php configurationlike this:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {                
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

After I update nginx to version 1.6.2 and upgrade linux, my php files not working. php requests are returning white pages, no errors.

(I can not find php-fpm.sock in my /var/run folder)

How can I restart PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace

```
include fastcgi_params;
```

with

```
include fastcgi.conf;
```

Comment: Thanks a million. My UniFi Video working again thanks to you!